# flexbox that keeps on piling items at another place when its space is finished

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a flex-box (or anything else) that will handle an flow of its items this way:!

(need 10 reputation for uploading images - does this make sense? - anyways, here is a link: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=b8f94fa)

looks like a board game ;-) but it should symbolize the way how items flow through that kind of grid. of course the number of items is variable.

greetings!

Comment: I just so happen to be trying to do the same exact thing for a kids web app I'm making. I will try a solution using various different content wrappers positioned at different locations on the page and rotated. The content wrappers will contain the various game board squares. When I have a solution I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

to answer my own question after a while:

css3 regions would be the means of choice..

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-regions/

Answer (score 0):

FLEX BOX SOLUTION:

To create a board game effect you can add the board game squares to groups and embed the groups within each other. Then different groups get different flex directions. Of course the number of sqaures contained in each group can easily be randomized in the javascript. I have not added that yet though.

Here is my code pen: 
http://codepen.io/nhmaggiej/pen/LEqvda

NOTE: I generated the markup via javascript here is the method I used in my backbone view:

```
createGameBoard: function(){
  var squares = $('.game', this.$el);
  var i = 0;
  while(squares.length > 0){
    var group = squares.splice(0, 2);
    var wrapper = $('<div class=\"group iteration' + i + '\"></div>');
    $(group).each(function(){
      wrapper.append($(this));
    });

    //if odd row

    if(i%2 != 0){

      $(wrapper).addClass('row');
    }


    if(i === 0){
      this.$el.append(wrapper);
    }else{
      $('.group').last().append(wrapper);
    }
    i++;
  }




}
```